# Writing to file a list where a unique string from column 1 gets multiple strings from column 2

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-columns, arcpy

I am totally new to python and need help.  I have a table that has 2 columns.  Column 1 contains the Genus and Column 2 contains Species.  I can iterate through the columns using SearchCursor and print out each row with a genus and a species.  What I need to do is print out a unique genus with all of its associated species.  So for example I have:

```
Acer    Maple
Acer    Sugar Maple
Acer    Purple Maple
Abies   Jack Pine
Abies    Spruce
```

I want

```
Acer|Maple|Sugar Maple|Purple Maple
Abies|Jack Pine|Spruce
```

I have tried but I can not figure out if I need a while loop, and if loop or a for loop.  When I try while and if my loops go on forever.

Here one attempt:

```
myCursor1=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FreqGISTable,["Genus","Species"])
for row in myCursor1:
    gisfile.write((row[0]).upper())
    if (row[0] == row[0]):
          gisfile.write(row[1])
    else:
         if (row[0] != row[0]):
            gisfile.write("END\n")

gisfile.close()
return gisfile
```

So thank you for the help. I had to tweak it a bit. The code works for the most part however, I need it to print all of the col2 items then print `"END_OPTIONS|\n"` at the very end of the line.

I have tried numerous ways to set it up but it doesn't work. `The line = row['col2'] + "|"` will not recognize the "|" and when I try to insert the final End Options it places it right after each col2 item.  Any suggestions to fix that?

Answer (score -1):

Here is one of the approach which answered by my friend Kavish:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Acer','Acer','Acer','Abies','Abies'], 'col2' : ['Maple','Sugar Maple','Purple Maple','Jack Pine','Spruce']})
df
```

```
col1    col2
0   Acer    Maple
1   Acer    Sugar Maple
2   Acer    Purple Maple
3   Abies   Jack Pine
4   Abies   Spruce
```

```
line = ""
classes = df['col1'].unique()
for c in classes:
    line = line + c + "|"
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if(row['col1'] == c):
            line = line + row['col2'] + "|"
    line = line[:-1]
    line = line + '\n'

print(line)

Acer|Maple|Sugar Maple|Purple Maple
Abies|Jack Pine|Spruce
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/12910033/kavish

Answer (score -1):

This is another approach that I think out of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Acer','Acer','Acer','Abies','Abies'], 'col2' : ['Maple','Sugar Maple','Purple Maple','Jack Pine','Spruce']})

copy = ""

df['col3'] = df['col1'].shift(1)

for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.col1 == row.col3:
        copy = copy + row.col2 + "|"
    elif row.col1 != row.col3:
        copy = copy + " \n" + row.col1 + "|" + row.col2 + "|"
        copy = copy[1:]

print(copy)
```